# What is the difference between belongsto and proper subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

if $A ⊂ B$, it means that $B$ must have the same but more element that $A$. Recall $A∈B$ read as $B$ is an element of the set $A$. my question is what is the difference between them?
for example let B = {1},    $A ={1}$.
clearly$A∈B$, but does $A ⊂ B$?
Thank you!

Comment: An element of a set is considered different from a singleton (one-element) subset. $1 \in \{1,2\}$ while $\{1\} \subset \{1, 2\}$.

Comment: @ angryavian , does that mean that ∈ can only use for element of set and that ⊂ , subset is only for 2 different sets?

Comment: for example can i do things like 1⊂{1,2} ?

Comment: For first getting used to the notation, it can be helpful to think of numbers like $1,2,3$ etc... as [ur-elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement), that is... "*they are just numbers and are not sets themselves.*"  In such an interpretation you very clearly have $1$ is not a subset of $\{1,2\}$ because $1$ is not even a set.  As you get further along, you'll formally define numbers using sets, so it is good to grow out of this sooner rather than later... but for now that is fine.

Comment: Do not confuse $\{1\}$ and $1$.  They are not equal.  The first is *a set containing the number 1* while the other is *just the number 1 itself*.  A lunch box containing a sandwich is not the same thing as a sandwich.  You can eat the sandwich.  You can eat the *contents* of the lunch box.  You can not eat the lunch box itself.